# What does 'from dot import asterisk' do in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

#### Question

What does the following line do in Python 3?

```
>>> from . import *
```

#### What I found out so far...

It does not output anything and the only change I can see in Python 3.7.3 is the following:

```
>>> '__warningregistry__' in locals()
False
>>> from . import *
>>> '__warningregistry__' in locals()
True
>>> locals()['__warningregistry__']
{'version': 0}
```

This might be part of the warnings module and indicates that there is a warning somewhere which is not printed, but the [documentation mentions only a variable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn_explicit) `__warningregistry__` in the the module `warnings`.

The documentation explains how `from . import foo` [works](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), and how `from bar import *` [works](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), but I couldn't find anything about `from . import *`. One might expect that all names from `__init__.py` are loaded into the current name space (as `from bla import *` would do for `bla.py`) but this doesn't seem to be the case and also it doesn't make sense when `__name__ == '__main__'` (scripts and terminal).

Python 2 behaves more similar to what I had expected:

```
>>> # Python 2.7.16
>>> from . import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

[PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) is quite illuminative but doesn't answer my question either.

Comment: As Python 2.7 says, it's a relative import, like those shown in one of your links: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: @ForceBru yes, but why doesn't it import anything then? When trying on the terminal I'd expect an error like `ImportError: cannot import name 'testmod' from '__main__' (unknown location)` if it is a relative import. I could add a minimal example too for doing the same in a package (where it doesn't import names from `__init__.py` either as I would have expected).

Comment: ``>>>`` indicates that you are executing this in an interactive shell, not a script. Which shell are you using?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm using the standard python terminal to avoid all the IPython magic. Please let me know if you cannot reproduce my examples, that would be even more confusing, though.

Comment: You may want to have a look at PEP 366: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/ I still haven't quite figured out what happens, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi PEP 366 is a good hint too, but it doesn't really explain the behavior, since it should be part of Python >= 2.6 as well as Python >= 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

When `__main__` is a script or interactive session, `.` is the `__main__` package itself:

```
$ python3 -c 'from . import float'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'float' from '__main__' (unknown location)
```

This makes `from . import *` a noop, with `__warningregistry__` added as a side-effect of the `import` machinery.

---

Relative imports from `__main__` were special-cased by [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/). This introduced `__package__` for relative package name lookup, *and* specifies that `__main__. __package__` has the special value `None`.

In addition, the module import spec [`__main__.__spec__` may be `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#main-spec) - namely in an interactive shell or when executing a script.

As it turns out, *any* module with `__package__ = __spec__ = None` will treat `.` as itself:

```
$ cat test.py
__package__ = __spec__ = None
from . import float
$ python3 -c 'import test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mfischer/PycharmProjects/lispy/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import float
ImportError: cannot import name 'float' from 'test' (./test.py)
```

---

The [`__warningregistry__` is added](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0cf832a9ef84be6e18aad02464814530d80b82b2/Lib/warnings.py#L327) because there is a [hidden warning from the missing attributes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0cf832a9ef84be6e18aad02464814530d80b82b2/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L1072). It is suppressed by default, but you can see it with [all warning enabled](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w):

```
$ python3 -Wa -c 'from . import float'
-c:1: ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, falling back on __name__ and __path__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'float' from '__main__' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't really understand it, though. `__main__` is a package and a module at the same time? Where does the name `__warningregistry__` come from then? `from __main__ import *` does not seem to create this name in `locals()`. Where does the difference between Python 2 and Python 3 come from in this particular case?

Comment: ``__warningregistry__`` comes from a hidden warning of the import machinery. I've added this to the answer as well now.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Why does `from . import *` not import all names form `__init__.py` in a package?